# Multiple sites hosted on NGNIX. How can I reach the correct one using the IP address?

Tags: nginx

I have an IP address, say 192.168.1.20, which has an NGINX server running two HTTP sites as subdomains, say:

- site1.domain.com
- site2.domain.com

If I go to site1.domain.com or site2.domain.com in a browser I am directed to the correct website. If I go to 192.168.1.20, I am directed to site1.

I assume NGINX is using headers to choose the appropriate location when accessed through a browser-- but I want to be able to reach site2.domain.com through the IP address. Do I need to add specific headers to the request somehow to do this, or is there a different way?

Comment: Can you clarify if you want  `site2.domain.com` to be shown *instead* of  `site1.domain.com` when accessed by IP `192.168.1.20` or do you want them *both* to be accessible by IPs instead of domain names?

Answer (score 2):

When hosting multiple websites, the webserver will use the `Host:` header to determine which website is being requested. If that header is missing, then the webserver will show the default website.

When specifying the domain name in the address bar of a browser, the browser will add the `Host:` header for you. This tells the server which website is being requested.

But when you specify the IP address in the address bar, you have not told the browser which URL to put in the `Host:` header.

If you must use the IP address to reach your server, then add the `Host:` header manually.

Comment: There is no such thing as an HTTP request without `Host: ` header. It MUST be present, otherwise server MUST respond with 400 (Bad Request) error. [It's all in the standards](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23). When accessing website via IP address the `Host` header will contain that IP address. No way it would be an empty value...

Comment: I was not aware that it was a required header (in the `HTTP/1.1` spec). So yes, the browser will put the IP address in the `Host:` header. The rest still holds though.

Comment: This should work if you want to manipulate headers

Comment: @Anubioz Apache doesn't respond with 400 Bad Request, in fact you don't need to send any headers at all... just tested it. I can't try Nginx but I bet the same is true.

Answer (score 0):

Add a default server command to the server2 block.

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name example.com;
   # etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't say if site2 has a different IP address that site1. If
   they share the same IP address, you are using name based virtual
   hosting and you cannot go to a specific site based on IP (the site
   is determined based on domain name). You'll need to assign an extra
   IP to site2. i.e. assign 1 IP per site
2. If you want to access only site2 via IP and don't care about site1 (you also don't say),
   the other answers may work for you. e.g set default site to be site2
3. Yes, you can also manipulate headers (Host:). You can also override
   DNS with /etc/hosts entries to access vhosts.

What if there are no headers?

```
telnet 192.168.1.20 80
Trying 192.168.1.20...
Connected to 192.168.1.20.
Escape character is '^]'.
get /
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
</html>
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Then you get the `default` site as configured. If you want another site, you either send headers or follow option **#1**.

Comment: But you can! Just use plain IP address as you would have used a normal host name - apache/nginx both support it without issues...

Comment: @Anubioz How? How would you differentiate between sites when using the same IP address and no DNS? I saw your answer, it doesn't make sense to me. Please explain.

Comment: Nginx shows `site1.domain.com` on `192.168.1.20` just because it goes first in the config (there is something like `server { server_name site1.domain.com; ...} ... server { server_name site2.domain.com; ...}` in that config). However, by specifying the IP address in the second `server` section like this:  `server { server_name 192.168.1.20 site2.domain.com; ...}` this default behaviour will be overridden, since it will now recognise `Host: 192.168.1.20` header sent by the client as a valid domain, which should be served from the second section.

Comment: Basically, IP address is actually the same to nginx/apache as a domain name, so anywhere where you could have used domain name, you can safely put an IP address...

Comment: @Anubioz If the OP does that, he/she will no longer be able to access site1 via IP... you get it??

Comment: Sure, but isn't it exactly the thing OP wants? To have site2 opened by IP instead of site1? How else would it work?

Comment: @Anubioz Nobody said `instead`, that was your assumption. I'm offering a solution that allows them to maintain access to both/all sites, rather than just changing the default site. I think my answer was fairly self explanatory. I'm not explaining any further.

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly is your solution? Access website with `telnet`? Get an extra IP and assign it to the website? What makes you believe that OP wants to access both sites by IP? I think it's clear that he wants site2 `instead` of site1...

Answer (score -1):

Just add desired IP address to `server_name` variable of the respected website:

```
server_name 192.168.1.20 site2.domain.com;
```

Alternatively you can create another `vhost` and use redirect:

```
server {
    listen 192.168.1.20:80;
    server_name _;
    return 301 http://site2.domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

This should allow desired domain to be opened by IP too..